# jQuery IF option selected

Tags: jquery, select

I am trying to check with jQuery if the select option with value = 1 is selected then add class to some elements. But something don't work. Can please some one look at the code?

My code :

```
Reservation <br/>
<select id="rReservation" name="rReservation" class="">
                                <option value="0">Maybe</option>
                                <option value="1">Sure</option>
</select>
<hr/>
Name <br/>
<input type="text" name="rCardUser" class="mRequired" />

<hr/>
Card<br/>
<input type="text" name="rCardNrr" class="mRequired" />
```

jQuery

```
if ($("#rReservation").val() == "1") {
   $('.mRequired').addClass('required');
} else {
   $('.mRequired').removeClass('required');
}
```

**LIVE example at fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/C7Gg3/**

Comment: The code looks just fine. What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need it inside an event handler:

```
$('#rReservation').change(function(){
    $('.mRequired').toggleClass('required', $(this).val() == '1');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/C7Gg3/1/

If you want it to trigger simply on load, you need to add `selected="selected"` to one of the options, because until one is "selected", `$('#rReservation").val()` will be `null`.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/C7Gg3/3/

Comment: Agreed. Didn't want to rewrite all his code, but for demo's sake it's worth a swap I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

You have to listen to the `change` event:

```
$("#rReservation").change(function(){
    if ($("#rReservation").val() == "1") {
       $('.mRequired').addClass('required');
    } else {
       $('.mRequired').removeClass('required');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/epkN8/

Comment: @Matt Anderson: Why not? He's trying to add/remove a class whenever an option is selected. The only way to do that, AFAIK, is to listen to  the `change` event. Am I missing something?

Comment: He said `I am trying to check with jQuery if the select option with value = 1 is selected then add class to some elements`. If he had added the "selected" property to either of his `<option>` tags, his code would work as is without an event listener.

Comment: @Matt Anderson: He has not phrased his question correctly. Take a look a the fiddle he provided, and you'll see what he's trying to do. That said, @AlienWebguy's answer is the more correct one, since it's terser, and it'll also remove the `required` class when the other option is selected.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to add/remove the class every time the `<select>` value changes:

```
$(function ()
{
    $("#rReservation").change()
    {
       $('.mRequired').toggleClass('required', $(this).val() == "1");
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting the use of toggle with the condition argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you've wrapped your code in a change event so that you're listening for the change happening.

http://jsfiddle.net/C7Gg3/2/

```
$('#rReservation').change(function(){ /* my code goes here */});
```